# rworldmap missing legendLabel

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am using rworldmap, but my map is mising one label in legend

```
mapDevice() #create world map shaped window
mapParams <- mapCountryData(sPDF
                        ,nameColumnToPlot="count"
                        ,addLegend=FALSE
                        ,catMethod = catMethod
                        ,colourPalette=colourPalette
                        ,mapTitle = "Count of all events by country"
                        ,oceanCol='lightblue'
                        ,missingCountryCol='white')
#adding legend
do.call(addMapLegend
    ,c(mapParams
       ,legendLabels="all"
       ,horizontal=TRUE
       ,legendWidth=0.5
       ,legendIntervals="data"
       ,legendMar = 11))
```

[image]

Thank you for any advice

Comment: What's object `sPDF`?: `Error in rwmCheckAndLoadInput(mapToPlot, inputNeeded = "sPDF", callingFunction = functionName) : 
  object 'sPDF' not found`

Comment: I simply wonder if this is because there is not enough space to add a number between 1 and 218.

Comment: There is an argument called `labelFontSize` in `addMapLegend()`. You may want to make font size smaller and see what happens.

Comment: I figured it out. There wasnt so much space to display it. I made the graph bigger and voila.

Comment: @Phil sPDF was my own object, I am sorry, I havent meantioned that.